# Swagger error when trying to import JSON

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I had defined an API successfully using query parameters but wanted to instead pass in all the state via a JSON object.

I have defined the following YAML file:

```
paths:
  /contact-us:
    post:
      summary: Contact Us
      description: |
        Originates a new conversation thread 
      consumes:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/RequestConversation'
      tags:
        - Email
      responses:
        200:
          description: New conversation has been originated
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Conversation'
```

This results in an error with the `parameters` line which states:

> Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf'

But I do have the following definition in the same YAML file:

```
definitions:
  RequestConversation:
    type: object
    properties:
      company_id:
        type: string
        # required: true
      user_email:
        type: string
        # required: true
      type:
        type: string
        # required: true
        default: 'contact-us'
      sub_type:
        type: string
      campaign:
        type: string
```

Also note that the "required" definitions are commented out and that's because they were giving me a different error:

> Expected type array but found type boolean

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved my own problem (at least the first part). Hopefully this will benefit someone else down the line:

1. The first issue was actually just that I hadn't specified a "name" property which is required.
2. This is still open (aka, it works but the "required" property can't be used).